# How to reset options on a printing dialog?

Tags: printing, pdf, evince

I have a network printer installed. In the printer properties dialog, I clearly have the printer option "Double sided printing" set to "On (Flip on Long Edge)", and the job option "Pages per side" set to "1":

[image]

[image]

However, when I open the print dialog of evince, I see 2 pages per slide and one-sided printing:

[image]

I was not able to change this to system defaults for the printer. Whatever I do, these two options stay the same. I re-installed the printer, I have removed all evince settings from ~/.config, ~/.local or ~/.gnome.

Answer (score 2):

I spent half an hour on this one, so I decided to put it here. I used `strace` to trace the system calls from evince, and found that evince tried to open the following files:

```
open("/etc/cups/lpoptions", O_RDONLY)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/january/.lpoptions", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/january/.cups/lpoptions", O_RDONLY) = 48
```

The third one was present and contained the offending options:

> Default XXX collate=false Duplex=None InputSlot=Default number-up=2
>   outputorder=normal PageSize=A4 position=center PrintoutMode=Normal
>   Quality=FromPrintoutMode scaling=100 wrap=false

Strangely, the file was there for the last two years, but apparently has not been used with evince running in 10.04, which I have recently replaced by 13.04. Removing it resulted in the correct settings taken over from the properties of the printer.