# How do I set the default value for the printing option "pages per side" in Google Chrome?

Tags: 18.04, printing, google-chrome

When I print from Google Chrome, it prints 6-up (ie: 6 pages per side) by default. To correct this I have to go to "More Settings → Print using system dialog... → Page Setup", change "Pages per side" to 1, and then print. Once I do this, it will stay at 1-up unless Google Chrome is restarted. If it is restarted, it reverts to 6-up as the default.

This only affects Chrome. If I open evince and go to print, I see the exact same dialog as Chrome's "Print using system dialog..." brings up, but the "Pages per side" defaults to 1.

None of the config files mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/344537/2583) contain the "6" on my system and this only affects Chrome so this is a different issue than the one in that question.

How do I set the default pages per side in Google Chrome to 1 so that it will survive a restart of Chrome?

In case it matters, I'm using google-chrome-stable 79.0.3945.88-1 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: You are likely looking at the wrong place: this should be part of the printer driver so is likely a cups setting not google chrome. https://www.cups.org/doc/options.html Probably N-Up Printing.

Comment: @Rinzwind If that is the case, why doesn't evince exhibit this behavior? I only see this behavior in Chrome, and Chrome reverts to it when Chrome is restarted, which makes me strongly suspect that it is Chrome-specific. Just to be sure, I tried `lpoptions -l PRINTERNAME` and also looked at the *Set Printer Options* page in the CUPS admin panel on my machine, and neither says anything about 6-up printing.

Comment: Is your chrome sandboxed?

Comment: @Rinzwind I don't understand your question. How would I determine if my chrome is sandboxed?